# How can i pass a value inside [ ] to API in angular?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular8

[image]

[image]

The First Image shows the output that i am getting and the second image is the output what i need.

i need the "admin" or whatever role i am using inside the square brackets like in the second picture.
How can i do that in angular?
NB: i am trying registration page using POST method.Thanks in Advance

Comment: why not change the value of role property to an array?

Comment: Pass an array of string instead of a string. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
const obj = {
  role: 'Admin'
}

newObj = {...obj, role: [obj.role]}

console.log(newObj)
```

**Update**

when the user selects a value in your dropdown you'll have a function to receive that value, should be something like this:

```
roleDropdownHandler(event) {
 const selectedRole = event.target.value;
 // Now to convert it into an array 
 const roleArray = [selectedRole];
}
```

Comment: Actually I'm using select where event option is used to target the values,                  
role: any = ['Admin', 'User']; This is how i have defined and these values needs to be updated to the provided API like above

Comment: okay, so you get the role from select dropdown? You mean change the strings to lowercase?

Comment: yeah i will get the role from dropdown, But my intention is, as you can see in the second image i need to pass the role element inside square brackets

Comment: is that a multi-select dropdown? after getting the value string, push that to an empty array and use that array as a value to the role property before sending.

Comment: Yes its a multi-select dropdown, Three roles are already defined in the DB and here i need to pass the values accordingly.

Comment: Consider this as an register page and we are allocating each user a role,Those roles are already assigned in the DB namely admin,user and HR,so here if i am clicking the role user that should define the role user.For that in DB we are accepting the values like ["admin"] only

Answer (score 0):

Just take an empty array and push selected value in that array. After that you can easily use that value in your payload.

```
if (event.target.value) {
    const role = [];
    role.push(event.target.value);
}
```